# Why I can't expand my layout's height bigger than 'MATCH_PARENT'

Tags: android, animation

I want my app listen 'click' event and then hide head and expand the body.

But it seems like I can only expand the body to 'MATCH_PARENT' at most.
When I expand the content to height smaller than 'MATCH_PARENT', then the code works, but if the height is bigger than 'MATCH_PARENT', then it doesn't work.

Here is my layout XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#000">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#e67e22"></RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_below="@id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e74c3c"
    ></RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this my Activity:

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final RelativeLayout header = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.header);
    final RelativeLayout content = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);

    content.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            header.animate().translationY(-header.getMeasuredHeight());
            content.animate().translationY(-header.getMeasuredHeight());
//          content.measure(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            final int originalHeight = content.getMeasuredHeight();
            final int targetHeight = content.getMeasuredHeight() + header.getMeasuredHeight();

            Animation a = new Animation()
            {
                @Override
                protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                    content.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                            ? targetHeight
                            : (int)(header.getMeasuredHeight()*interpolatedTime + originalHeight);
                    content.requestLayout();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                    return true;
                }
            };

            a.setDuration(500);
            content.startAnimation(a);
        }
    });
}
```

before click:

[image: before_animation]

after click:

[image: after_animation]

Comment: `match_parent`  will cover full screen, say highest value. if you will go beyond it. layout will be invisible in other words.

Comment: How is that supposed work, a height bigger than match_parent? I think it's pretty neat if Android prevents this from being possible. It shows Android is a little more sophisticated than html/css.

Comment: Try: delete android:layout_below="@id/header" from second RelativeLayout and add android:layout_above="@id/content" to first RelativeLayout. Also add alignParentBottom=true to second RelativeLayout

Comment: use parent layout as linear layout ..

Comment: Why don't you use `LinearLayout`??

Comment: @Shvet , hi, but actually my app's body height is smaller than the screen height(please see my picture), can you give me some advises, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, replace the outside RelativeLayout with LinearLayout solves my problem.